# Get Favicon of any website from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get the favicon of a website and show it like on this codepen :https://codepen.io/adrianverdau/pen/MyybWr
But it's not authorized from a chrome extension, I've already tried many things like this :

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

But that not helped me, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried using the URL `'https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' + location.hostname`?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Unmitigated, but it's not working, I've tried : <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=developer.mozilla.org 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"> with mozilla HostName but same error :(

Comment: I've solved the problem by migrate my code from popup.html to options.html (I'm developing a Chrome extension). I think Chrome block the usage of this type of script from his popup with Manifest 3. But the more important is that I've find a solution. Thank you so much for your help !